# Make a script in python that lists adjacent words through Unix?

Tags: python

How can I write a script in python through nested dictionaries that takes a `txt` file written as,

```
a,c,f,g,hi,lw:1

f,g,j,ew,f,h,a,w:3

fd,s,f,g,s:4
```

and make it print for each entry before the **:** character,  all neighbors it showed up next to

```
a: c h w

c: a f

f: c g ew h s

hi: g lw
```

and so on